# CRC24Q implementation

Tags: crc, crc32

I am trying to implement the algorithm of a CRC check, which basically created a value, based on an input message.
So, consider I have a hex message 3F214365876616AB15387D5D59, and I want to obtain the CRC24Q value of the message.
The algorithm that I found to do this is the following:

```
typedef     unsigned long crc24;
crc24 crc_check(unsigned char *input) {
        unsigned char *octets; 
        crc24 crc = 0xb704ce; // CRC24_INIT;
        int i;
        int len = strlen(input); 
    octets = input;

    while (len--) {
        crc ^= ((*octets++) << 16); 

        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            crc <<= 1; 
            if (crc & 0x1000000) 
                crc ^= CRC24_POLY;
        }
    }
    return crc & 0xFFFFFF;
}
```

where *input=3F214365876616AB15387D5D59.
The problem is that ((*octets++) << 16) will shift by 16 bits the ascii value of the hex character and not the character itself.
So, I made a function to convert the hex numbers to characters.
I know the implementation looks weird, and I wouldn't be surprised if it were wrong.
This is the convert function:

```
char* convert(unsigned char* message) {
    unsigned char* input;
    input = message;
    int p;

    char *xxxx[20];
    xxxx[0]="";

    for (p = 0; p < length(message) - 1; p = p + 2) {
        char* pp[20];
        pp[0] = input[0];
        char *c[20];
        *input++;
        c[0]= input[0];
        *input++;
        strcat(pp,c);
        char cc;
        char tt[2];
        cc = (char ) strtol(pp, &pp, 16);
        tt[0]=cc;
        strcat(xxxx,tt);

    }
    return xxxx;
}
```

SO:

```
unsigned char *msg_hex="3F214365876616AB15387D5D59";
crc_sum = crc_check(convert((msg_hex)));
printf("CRC-sum: %x\n", crc_sum);
```

Thank you very much for any suggestions.

Comment: Please don't re-ask the same question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the `if (crc & 0x8000000)` be `if (crc & 0x1000000)` otherwise you're testing the 28th bit not the 25th for 24-bit overflow

Comment: Yes, you are right. It was a mistake. It's supposed to b 10000000. I have run it like this and the result is still different from the correct one.